# if else statement in dax function

Tags: powerbi, dax

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a tableau dashboard where I have parameter having values like US and Canada,APAC and Overall.

And I have department values like Central,Georgia,Hyd and Pune

My requirement is If I select region as US and Canada then I need to show only Central,Georgia

```
                           If I select region as APAC then I need to show only Hyd,Pune

                            If I select region as Overall then I need to show All 4.i.e, Central,Georgia,Hyd,Pune
```

Below is my logic in Tableau and I am not sure how to write in power BI as I am new.

Could some one help how to write

I created a table inside power BI for the parameter values and not sure how to write after that

````
when 'US and Canada' then
[Department] = 'Central' or
[Department]= 'Georgia'
when 'APAC' then
[Department] = 'Hyd' or
[Department]= 'Pune'

when 'Overall' then
[Department] = 'Central' or
[Department] = 'Georgia' or
[Department]= 'Hyd' or
[Department] = 'Pune'
END```



[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/21WLw.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECJ5r.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Let's go step by step. I first created a table with real data to test my code:

Here is my table:

[image: Test_Table]

Now Let's add a [new column] command from the menu:

Solution_01 : Using a calculated column in your table:

```
Calc_Column =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    [Region] = "US-Canada", "Central,Georgia",
    [Region] = "APAC", "Hyd,Pune ",
    -- This is else block [Region] = "Overall"
    "Central,Georgia,Hyd,Pune "
)
```

And If we test it, It returns :

[image: DEDE]

Solution_02 : Creating a new measure and selecting any region from [Region] slicer:

Note: Create a slicer, and put [region] into the slicer, then you can create a visual card to see the result.

```
Calc_Measure =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( YourTable[Region] ) = "US-Canada", "Central,Georgia",
    SELECTEDVALUE ( YourTable[Region] ) = "APAC", "Hyd,Pune",
    -- This is else block [Region] = "Overall"
    "Central,Georgia,Hyd,Pune"
)
```

If we test it: It returns:

[image: Multiple Slicers]

It returns (Central Georgia Hyd Pune); because Multiple region is selected in my slicer. If you select only "US" or "Canada" in your slicer, Result will show (Central Georgia).

I hope It solves your problem.

Comment: Hi @ozansen,  Its not working

Comment: Sorry! I will correct it now.

Comment: I updated it . Please check it now.

Comment: Hi @ozansen here if I select region as APAC I need to show the deparmenets which having values Hyd , Pune.The solutuon you gave is not giving the answer

Comment: Then create a measure instead of a column.  I will put the measure at the bottom. You need to use selectedvalue() function to get region from a slicer or etc...

Comment: Could you please help on it.I am new to power bi

Comment: Of course, No problem. I am here to help you! I added it in the bottom.

Comment: Im sorry still no luck

Comment: OK. I will test with real data and show you the results screen. Stay here.

Comment: Hi, I updated the solution from scratch, please test it.

Comment: Hi Ozan  below is my requirement   .
Here Region table is hardcoded values created inside power bi
Region Table (Created inside power bI)
US-Canada
APAC
Overall

Department Table
Georgia
Central
Hyd

Output Required is  
If I select Region as Us_Canada then need to show 2 departments Georgia
 Central
 
If I select Region as APAC then need to show 2 departments Hyd
 Pune
 
If I select Region as APAC then need to show 2 departments Hyd
 Pune
 
If I select Region as Overall then need to show all departments Department Table
 Georgia
 Central
 Hyd

Comment: Hi, You can do it already easily. I did it for you this time; but You need to do it yourself. Please no more questions.